# Breaking long HTML lines while reading the source code

Tags: java, html

I am extracting the HTML source code in Java by

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet); 
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) 
{ 
sourcepage = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8"); 
} 
client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

This code is the baseline of my code and I am going to perform different functions on each line of the HTML code. However, some lines of the code are too long. For instance, length of a line is 49966 which makes some computational cost problems while running the code. I am wondering if it is possible to break the HTML line -if its length is greater than a threshold- while reading the HTML source code?

This is also how I read the code line by line:

```
String[] each_line = sourcepage.split("\r?\n");
```

Comment: What programming language are you doing this from?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw Sorry I forgot to mention that. I am using Java.

Comment: Please show some additional code, how are you parsing the response?

Comment: @Nit I modified the post. You can find more details there. Thank you

Comment: Why don't you simply use a HTML parser?

Answer (score 0):

That depends a bit on what you want to do with the HTML afterwards. If you just want to read it, then you can add a newline after every HTML element that ends with `/>` (i.e. `content.replace("/>", "/>\n")` plus you can do a regexp search for `</[^>]+>` and put a newline after each match.

That should break the HTML quite nicely. Note: Usually, regexp is not the right tool to process HTML. But in this special case, it's enough.

Another option is to add [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) as a dependency to your code. It has code formatters that beautify HTML.